# Check between class for existence a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want check if there is not class `.myclass2` in classs `.myclass1` alert ok but it don't work in my try:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/uyKvh/

```
<div class="myclass1">
    <div class="myclass2">1</div>
</div>
<div class="myclass1">
    <div class="myclass2">1</div>
</div>



if($(".myclass1:not(:has(.myclass2))")){
    alert('ok');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any jquery selector returns an object, so it always evaluates to true.

Use the length to check if results were returned..

```
if( $(".myclass1:not(:has(.myclass2))").length ){
    alert('ok');
}
```

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/uyKvh/4/

Comment: That will execute the `alert` if at least one `.myclass1` doesn't contain a `.myclass2` element. But I think the OP wants the `alert` to be executed only when all `.myclass1` elements don't have a `.myclass2` element...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, true... still not sure what the OP really wants though ... It seemed to me that he might want to perform some action on the `.myclass1` elements that do not contain a `.class2` element..

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
if( $( '.myclass1:has(.myclass2)' ).length === 0 ) {
    alert( 'ok' );
}
```

So, you query for all `.myclass1` elements that contain a `.myclass2` element, and if there aren't any, you execute your code (`alert`, etc.)...

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it:

```
if($(".myclass1:not(:has(.myclass2))").length){
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uyKvh/6/

Comment: @Niels, this will not work if there is no inner element inside `.myclass1` **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/uyKvh/5/)**